# Close AHK script with powershell command

Tags: powershell, autohotkey

I created this post because I couldn't comment on @PBeezy response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700383/how-do-i-stop-an-active-autohotkey-script) question, and his answer for terminating a specific script does not work for me. He suggests doing:

```
wmic process where "commandline like '%%MyScript.ahk'" delete
```

However when I do this I get: `No Instance(s) Available` and the script doesn't close. I have substituted `MyScript` for the name of my ahk script. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard match provided is unlikely to match successfully, as the commandline of the process most likely does not end in `MyScript.ahk`

Running `wmic process where "commandline like '%%MyScript.ahk%%'" delete` will successfully match and stop the correct process, but it may be too greedy and stop other processes as well.